# Conversion for param and stored procedure not working

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to start usign stored procedures. Well, I currently have a query that is just returning a single value that is a string. I can't seem to see what I am doing incorrectly here.

The sql is below:

```
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @ReturnVal Varchar(20)

-- Insert statements for procedure here
set @ReturnVal = (select a.AccBCPublicId from [MyTable Goes Here] a where a.AccId = @ACCId)

return @ReturnVal
```

END

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[My Stored Procedure]", sqlConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
  {
    //clean the starting 0's before sending. Originally had leading zeros
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACCId", strAccId.TrimStart(Convert.ToChar("0"))));
    SqlParameter returnParam = new SqlParameter("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20) {Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue };
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(returnParam);

    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();   

    string bcAccount = (string)returnParam.Value;
 }
```

I keep getting the following error. I do see why it is seeing as int value type.

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'bc:99988' to data type int.
```

Comment: Sounds like your `AccId` is `int` type but you provide it  `bc:99988` as string.

Comment: Put a break point and check if your TrimStart works .... it doesn't seems so to be honest.

Comment: Thats what I thought but it is sending in a different value. all int. The bc: value is the PCPublicId being returned.

Comment: Yep the trimming is working. I just debug checked again. The AccId has no characters, only leading zeros. The bc: value the error is talking about is what I return when I run the procedure straight from SQL. Like it is assuming it has to convert (bc:9999) to int for some reason.

Comment: I think the ToChar conversion is not correct, if you have a number that has to be converted in a string you have to use the ToString function ToChar converts to a single character I presume...

Answer (score 1):

A value passed with the [RETURN T-SQL statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) can only be an integer expression, you can't pass back a string. It seems that the simplest option is to use ExecuteScalar

```
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select a.AccBCPublicId from [MyTable Goes Here] a where a.AccId = @ACCId
```

And in your code use

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(.....))
{
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(.....)
    object result = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    if(result != null)
        string bcAccount = result.ToString();
    ....
}
```

Comment: I did not knop that, and that explains it.  Thanks.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks, and now I will remember that.